# Rendering a Sliced Text effect with Fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

I am attempting to do a sliced Text effect with fabric.js exactly similar to [this](https://codepen.io/TajShireen/pen/ExLWgGb). However, up until now I haven't had success at all with understanding how clipping works in fabric.js.

Here is what I have until now which is far from it. The problem I am seeing is that even though the path is define looks like the area I like to be clipped, I see the text moving to the edge of the screen. I read on Fabric.js documentation about this:

> Please note: the clipPath is positioned starting from the center of the object. The object's originX and originY values do not play any role, while clipPath originX and originY do.

```js
// Create a canvas element
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");

// Create a text object with a large font size
var textTop = new fabric.Text("SLICED", {
  fontSize: 200,
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  fill: "white"
});

var textBottom = fabric.util.object.clone(textTop);
// Modify the cloned text object
textBottom.set({
  left: textTop.left - 2,
  top: textTop.top + 2
});

// Create a rectangle as the clipping mask
var clipPolyTop = new fabric.Polygon(
  [
    { x: textTop.left, y: textTop.top + textTop.height * 0.58 },
    { x: textTop.left + textTop.width, y: textTop.top + textTop.height * 0.48 },
    { x: textTop.left + textTop.width, y: textTop.top + textTop.height },
    { x: textTop.left, y: textTop.top + textTop.height },
    { x: textTop.left, y: textTop.top + textTop.height * 0.58 }
  ],
  {
    fill: "black"
  }
);

var clipPolyBottom = new fabric.Polygon(
  [
    { x: textBottom.left, y: textBottom.top + textBottom.height * 0.58 },
    { x: textBottom.left, y: textBottom.top },
    { x: textBottom.left + textBottom.width, y: textBottom.top },
    {
      x: textBottom.left + textBottom.width,
      y: textBottom.top + textBottom.height * 0.48
    },
    { x: textBottom.left, y: textBottom.top + textBottom.height * 0.58 }
  ],
  {
    fill: "black"
  }
);

// Set the clipping path of the text to the clipping mask
textTop.clipPath = clipPolyTop;
textBottom.clipPath = clipPolyBottom;

// Add the text and clipping mask to the canvas
canvas.add(textTop, textBottom);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
:root {
  --background-color: black;
  --text-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  font-size: clamp(1.5rem, 1rem + 18vw, 15rem);
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: var(--text-color);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="wrapper">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1400" height="1400"></canvas>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Also at: https://codepen.io/ssarangi/pen/ZEqmdbR

Would really appreciate someone showing me where I am going wrong in understanding the coordinate system here for fabric.